# Why some tags can be nested in other tags and not the other way round

Tags: html

I came across an article a while ago which explained why some HTML tags can be nested in some tags and some tags cannot do that. But I forgot the keywords that describe this design in the browser/HTML specification to validate a valid HTML. I believe that there are two keywords that describe this, but I forgot them. Can someone help me out?

The keywords are not structural/presentation.

All I remember that the two keywords are handy to remember why some HTML tags can be nested in some tags, but not in some tags.

For instance

```
<p><div></div></p>
```

is not valid HTML

Thanks

Comment: I suspect you're looking for "block" and "inline", but HTML no longer uses those categorisations.

Comment: Thanks  Alohci and Dany for answering my query. It is not a "block" or "inline" that I was looking for.  At that time, I mentioned this to a developer who has 10 years of experience but he has not heard of that terms before. Inline can be in a block , but this still not explain why is this allowed ? What term in the specification explains that WHY an inline element can be inside in a block element ? Why?? what terms can be used to describe this behaviour? Can we put <div> inside <a href=""> div </a> ? If not, why ? If we can, why is that we can do so ?

Comment: Deep down, there is often no why. There's some rules of thumb based on semantics, some rules that are imposed to aid certain classes of users, such as those that use accessibility technologies, and some other rules based on technical limitations imposed by the history of HTML and the need for backward compatibility. These guide the formal rules, but ultimately those formal rules just amount to a bag of rules it's advisable to follow. Sometimes that advice changes, like <div> in <a> which was not valid in HTML4, but is in some circumstances in HTML5.

Comment: Thank you very much, Alohci for your further comments.

Answer (score 1):

As one comment suggests, you're probably thinking of "**block**" elements (which break the flow of content, have 100% default width and can contain other elements) and "**inline**" elements (don't break the content flow so they won't create a text line of their own, their width adjusts to the content and are not containers in nature).

This is mentioned in HTML4: https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.3

> Generally, block-level elements may contain inline
>   elements and other block-level elements. (...) inline elements
>   may contain only data and other inline elements. Inherent in this
>   structural distinction is the idea that block elements create "larger"
>   structures than inline elements.(...) Generally,
>   block-level elements begin on new lines, inline elements do not.

The HTML5 spec, however, will talk about categories instead: https://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/#categories

HTML4 used inline and block-level but HTML5 says:

> HTML does not use the terms "*block-level*" or "*inline*" as part of its
>   content model rules, to reduce confusion with CSS.

So these terms may now be better suited to a type of **CSS display** rendering mechanism.